# Idea about creating a html file from xml+xslt in Perl

Tags: html, xml, perl, xslt

My aim is to generate an `HTMl` file from two XML and `XSLT` files. I have looked over net ans find no good suggestion which I could do the same way. What I understand when I add the lines

```
<xsl:output method="html" ..... />
```

I could see the output as `HTML`. But my goal is having a new file whic I could save it via Perl script and seeing the result. I don't know if it is possible or not. I'll be glad to know if is so.

I would be pleased if someone let me know any idea that help me.

Here are my `XML` and `XSLT` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<Summary>
  <test name="test">
    <xml_name name="ABC">
        <version num="104">
            <component name="APPS">
                <componenet_ver>104</componenet_ver>
            </component>
        <component name="Ner">
            <componenet_ver>1.0</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="HUNE">
                <componenet_ver>003</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="FADA">
                <componenet_ver>107</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="VEDA">
                <componenet_ver>8.8</componenet_ver>
            </component>
        </version>
    </xml_name>
  </test>
</Summary>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Summary/test">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr bgcolor="Peru">
                    <th>Components</th>
                    <th>Versions</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//component">
                    <xsl:variable name="CompomName" select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="VerName" select="description"/>
                    <tr>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$CompomName}"> </td>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$VerName}"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>                                 
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want to use XSLT (1.0) in your Perl code then see http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.94/LibXSLT.pm on how to do that.

Comment: What are you struggeling with? Are you looking for an XSLT processor, or you want to make the result of the processing downloadable?

Comment: For sure downloadable for me very good. I aim at having an HTML file as output from Perl document

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, your hint caused to find the solution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried a lot in this issue, I found out it could be done by a simple code. I am writing the code here for someone maybe would have the same question as I had:

```
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;

my $XML_FILENAME = "test.xml";
my $XSL_FILENAME = "test.xslt";
my $OUTPUT_FILENAME = "test.html";

my $xml_parser  = XML::LibXML->new;
my $xslt_parser = XML::LibXSLT->new;

my $xml         = $xml_parser->parse_file($XML_FILENAME);
my $xsl         = $xml_parser->parse_file($XSL_FILENAME);

my $stylesheet  = $xslt_parser->parse_stylesheet($xsl);
my $results     = $stylesheet->transform($xml);
my $output      = $stylesheet->output_string($results);

# the main command and of course the easiest one
$stylesheet->output_file($results, $OUTPUT_FILENAME);
```

Comment: By the way more explanation can be found here:
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch22_08.htm